# Using while loop in converting an english phrase to PigLatin

Tags: string, loops, while-loop, return

For my assignment I have a method where i have to add two strings in or out the while loop, the strings are to make a piglatin phrase while they are converting an englishword to piglatin and adding on the phrase to make a pigLatinPhase...
Note: it is returning the pigLatinPhrase.
This is all i have going on in this method:

```
public static String convertPhrase(String englishPhrase) { 
    Scanner englishScanner = new Scanner(englishPhrase);
     String pigLatinPhrase;
    while (englishScanner.hasNext()) {
        String pigLatinWord = convertWord(englishPhrase);
        String englishPhrase1 = englishScanner.next();
        String phrase = "";
        String pigLatinPhrase1 = pigLatinWord + englishPhrase1;
    }
    return pigLatinPhrase;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare and initialize the phrase variable before you start the loop and build it as you go using your convert function

```
public static String convertPhrase(String englishPhrase) {

    Scanner englishScanner = new Scanner(englishPhrase);
    String pigLatinPhrase = "";
    while (englishScanner.hasNext()) {
        String pigLatinWord = convertWord(englishScanner.next());
        String sp = (pigLatinPhrase.length() == 0) ? "" : " ";
        pigLatinPhrase = pigLatinPhrase + sp + pigLatinWord;
    }
    return pigLatinPhrase;
}
```

Comment: I got my piglatin phrase to print out right but now I'm pretty sure i need a fence loop to seperate each piglatin word. how would you go about that? i know i have to take the first piglatin would out and add a space to it.

Comment: The code I added for the variable sp will add a space to each word after the first

Comment: Thank you very much! but id like to under stand the **(pigLatinPhrase.length() == 0) ? "" : " ";** part, mind explaining?

Comment: It's a shorthand for an if else statement whose output is returned to the variable so in this case if the length of the pigLatinPhrase is 0 the value of sp will be "" otherwise it will be " " the structure is  variable = (condition) ? Condition true value : condition false value; so it's the equivalent of if(pigLatinPhrase.length() == 0) { sp = ""; } else { sp = " ";}